# How to remove leading and trailing spaces at comma and single quotes from string

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a input csv file with format

```
SN,Date,TIME,Line,MatchedLine
C0001 , Mar 22 , 02:50:25, '"heartbeat"', '"kernel: heartbeat event \n"'
C0002 , Mar 22 , 02:50:25, '"Wait max"', '"kernel:  Wait max 12 seconds and start polling eCM \n"'
```

and I was trying to convert whole csv file to array of hashes such that each headers will be mapped to respective columns as below.

```
 [{"SN"=>"C0001", "Date"=>"Mar 22", "TIME"=>"02:50:25", "Line"=>"heartbeat", "MatchedLine"=>"kernel: heartbeat event \\n"},
  {"SN"=>"C0002", "Date"=>"Mar 22", "TIME"=>"02:50:25", "Line"=>"Wait max", "MatchedLine"=>"kernel:  Wait max 12 seconds and start polling eCM \\n"}]
```

and i have a function for doing this

```
  def csv_to_hash file
    words_list_hash  = []
    csv_file = File.open(file.strip,"r:bom|utf-8")
    csv_data = CSV.read csv_file
    headers = csv_data.shift.map {|i| i.to_s }
    string_data = csv_data.map {|row| row.map {|cell| cell.to_s } } 
    words_list_hash = string_data.map {|row| Hash[*headers.zip(row).flatten] }
    return words_list_hash
end
```

but it was throwing an error at the time it is reading csv file (CSV.read csv_file)

```
 /home/tivo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/csv.rb:1925:in `block (2 levels) in shift': Illegal quoting in line 3. (CSV::MalformedCSVError)
```

and i found that this is because of improper input , 
if i remove the leading and trailing spaces and single quotes before the string the code is working properly

```
 C0001,Mar 22,02:50:25,"heartbeat","kernel: heartbeat event \n"'
```

can anyone tell me how to format the whole csv file to mentioned format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# read as string
csv = File.read file.strip, "r:bom|utf-8"
# parse and separate header and the rest
head, *rest = csv.split($/).map { |row| row.split(/["']*\s*,\s*['"]*/) }
# produce the hash requested
rest.map { |row| head.zip(row).to_h }
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#           "Date" => "Mar 22",
#           "Line" => "heartbeat",
#    "MatchedLine" => "kernel: heartbeat event \\n\"'",
#             "SN" => "C0001",
#           "TIME" => "02:50:25"
#  },
#  [1] {
#           "Date" => "Mar 22",
#           "Line" => "Wait max",
#    "MatchedLine" => "kernel:  Wait max 12 seconds and start polling eCM \\n\"'",
#             "SN" => "C0002",
#           "TIME" => "02:50:25"
#  }
# ]
```